# Getting all queue names of a queue manager

Tags: java, api, websphere, ibm-mq

I am using Java API for WMQ.

I have seen that RFHUTIL is able to load all queue names in a drop down list for a queue manager.

Same way, I wanted to get all queue names for a queue manager in a list.

It is being done by RFHUTIL, so definitely it is possible.
I checked the functions available for MQQueueManager class but could find any solution.

Need some advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Listing queue names in a queue manager is an administrative job. You have to use Programmable Command Format (PCF) classes to do that. There are number of PCF commands to create, delete, list queue, channels, etc. This [link](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wmqv7/v7r5/topic/com.ibm.mq.doc/zr00120_.htm) describes PCF in detail.

For listing queues you can use MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q or MQCMD_INQUIRE_Q_NAMES PCF command. There are samples shipped with MQ. There is `PCF_DisplayActiveLocalQueues.java` is a useful one for you.

Comment: One more help please. How not to load the system queue names?

Comment: I don't think you can set filter a for not listing SYSTEM.* queues because the queue name parameter can't have a filter. You can specify a absolute or generic names only. But you can consider filtering out SYSTEM.* queues after listing.